# How to move a component in Sonatype Nexus 3?

Tags: groovy, nexus, sonatype

I'm trying to promote a component together with all it's assets from our staging repo to the released repo. So far I've managed to create the component so that it get's detected when trying to recreate it but it won't show up in searches or browsing. I'm pretty sure I need to emit an event for it to show up but even after rebuilding the indexes it won't show up so I must have missed something else as well.

```
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.Asset                                                                                                                                                               
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.Query                                                                                                                                                               
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.Component                                                                                                                                                           
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.StorageFacet                                             

import groovy.json.JsonOutput                                                                         
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper                                                                        

def request = new JsonSlurper().parseText(args)                                                       
assert request.fromRepoName: 'fromRepo parameter is required'
assert request.toRepoName: 'toRepo parameter is required'
assert request.artifactId: 'artifactId parameter is required'
assert request.groupId: 'groupId parameter is required'
assert request.version: 'version parameter is required'

log.info("Moving ${request.groupId}:${request.artifactId}:${request.version} from ${request.fromRepoName} to ${request.toRepoName}")

def fromRepo = repository.repositoryManager.get(request.fromRepoName)
def toRepo = repository.repositoryManager.get(request.toRepoName)                                                                                                                                                
StorageFacet fromStorageFacet = fromRepo.facet(StorageFacet)
StorageFacet toStorageFacet = toRepo.facet(StorageFacet)
def fromTx = fromStorageFacet.txSupplier().get()                                                      
def toTx = toStorageFacet.txSupplier().get()     
try {                                            
    fromTx.begin()                               
    log.info("Transaction started for repo: ${request.fromRepoName}")
    Iterable<Component> components = fromTx.
            findComponents((Query.builder().where('name == ').param(request.artifactId).and('group == ').param(request.groupId) & 'version == ').param(request.version).build(), [fromRepo])
    log.info("Trying to get component.")         
    component = components.iterator().next()     
    try {                                        
        toTx.begin()
        log.info("Transaction started for repo: ${request.toRepoName}")                                                                                                                                          
        if (toTx.componentExists(component.group(), component.name(), component.version(), toRepo)) {                                                                                                            
            log.info("Component already exists, deleting.")
            Iterable<Component> componentsToDelete = toTx.
                    findComponents((Query.builder().where('name == ').param(request.artifactId).and('group == ').param(request.groupId) & 'version == ').param(request.version).build(), [toRepo])
            log.info("Trying to get component.")
            componentToDelete = componentsToDelete.iterator().next()
            toTx.deleteComponent(componentToDelete)
        }
        log.info("Creating new component with name: ${component.name()}, group: ${component.group()}, version: ${component.version()} in repo ${request.toRepoName}")
        newComponent = toTx.createComponent(toTx.findBucket(toRepo), toRepo.getFormat())
                .name(component.name())
                .group(component.group())
                .version(component.version())
                .attributes(component.attributes())
        newComponent.setEntityMetadata(component.getEntityMetadata())
        log.info("Component metadata: ${component.getEntityMetadata()}")
        log.info("New component successfully created.")
        fromTx.browseAssets(component).each {Asset asset ->
log.info("Attaching ${asset.name()} to new component.")                                   
            log.info("Asset metadata: ${asset}") 
            newAsset = toTx.createAsset(toTx.findBucket(toRepo), newComponent)                        
                    .name(asset.name())          
                    .attributes(asset.attributes())                                                   
            newAsset.setEntityMetadata(asset.getEntityMetadata())                                     
            log.info("Asset entityMetadata: ${asset.getEntityMetadata()}")                                                                                                                                       
            log.info("New asset metadata: ${newAsset}")                                               
            log.info("Trying to save asset.")    
            toTx.saveAsset(newAsset)                                                                  
        }                                        
        toTx.saveComponent(newComponent)         
        toTx.commit()                            
        log.info("Transaction commited for repo: ${request.toRepoName}")                              
    } finally {                                  
        toTx.close()                             
    }                                            
    log.info("Deleting component with name: ${component.name()}, group: ${component.group()}, version: ${component.version()} in repo ${request.fromRepoName}")                                                  
    fromTx.deleteComponent(component)            
    fromTx.commit()                              
    log.info("Transaction commited for repo: ${request.fromRepoName}")                                                                                                                                           
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                
finally {
    fromTx.close()
}

def result = JsonOutput.toJson([
        status: "Success"
])
return result
```

For added context I'm trying to setup a CI/CD flow with Jenkins Pipelines & Maven based on this: https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/new-way-do-continuous-delivery-maven-and-jenkins-pipeline

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you solved this already but seems like I am trying to achieve a very similar solution.

I've found that if I add the assets into the destination repository using the MavenFacet or RawContentFacet (depending on the underlying repository format) and using the put method then the uploaded assets do show up in browse and search.

This is the code I have come up with:

```
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.StorageFacet
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.transaction.TransactionalStoreBlob
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.payloads.BlobPayload
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.Component
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.Query
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.maven.MavenFacet
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.maven.internal.Maven2Format
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.raw.RawContentFacet
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.raw.internal.RawFormat
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.Asset
import org.sonatype.nexus.blobstore.api.BlobStoreManager
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.manager.RepositoryManager

RepositoryManager rManager = repository.repositoryManager
BlobStoreManager bManager = blobStore.blobStoreManager

def STAGING = 'staging'
def input = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(args)
for (item in input.items) {
    assert item.to: 'item.to parameter is required'
    assert item.group: 'item.group parameter is required'
    assert item.artifact: 'item.artifact parameter is required'
    assert item.version: 'item.version parameter is required'

    assert item.to != STAGING: 'item.to cannot be the staging area'

    // Check the repository exists
    def toRepo = repository.repositoryManager.get(item.to)
    assert toRepo: 'item.to is not a valid repository name'

    // Currently only support these payload types
    assert [Maven2Format.NAME, RawFormat.NAME].contains(toRepo.getFormat().toString()): 'Unknown Format ' + toRepo.getFormat().toString()
}

def repo = rManager.get(STAGING)
def tx = repo.facet(StorageFacet).txSupplier().get()

def deNest = new ArrayList()
try
{
    tx.begin()
    for (item in input.items) {
        Iterable<Component> components = tx.findComponents(
            Query.builder().where('name == ').param(item.artifact).and('group == ').param(item.group)
            .and('version == ').param(item.version).build(), [repo])

        Component component = components.iterator().next();
        tx.browseAssets(component).each { Asset asset ->
            def br = asset.requireBlobRef()
            deNest.add([
                to: item.to,
                store: br.getStore(),
                blobId: br.getBlobId(),
                asset: asset.name(),
                contentType: asset.contentType()
            ])
        }
    }
    tx.commit()
}
finally
{
    tx.close()
}

for (dn in deNest) {
    def toRepo = rManager.get(dn.to)
    def payload = new BlobPayload(bManager.get(dn.store).get(dn.blobId), dn.contentType)
    TransactionalStoreBlob.operation.withDb(toRepo.facet(StorageFacet).txSupplier()).call {
        switch (toRepo.getFormat().toString()) {
            case Maven2Format.NAME:
                def toTx = toRepo.facet(MavenFacet)
                toTx.put(toTx.mavenPathParser.parsePath(dn.asset), payload)
            break
            case RawFormat.NAME:
                def toTx = toRepo.facet(RawContentFacet)
                toTx.put(dn.asset, payload)
            break
            default:
                throw new RuntimeException('Unknown Format ' + toRepo.getFormat().toString())
        }
    }
}

return groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson([success: true])
```

Answer (score 0):

The script below works for NPM repositories within a single blob. Haven't tried it for other cases. Nexus 3.43.0-01

```
import groovy.json.JsonOutput
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.Format
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.manager.RepositoryManager
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.Asset
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.Component
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.Query
import org.sonatype.nexus.repository.storage.StorageFacet

def request = new JsonSlurper().parseText(args);
assert request.srcRepoName: 'srcRepoName parameter is required';
assert request.dstRepoName: 'dstRepoName parameter is required';

def resultCode = 0;
def errMessage = '';

log.info('Try to sync assets from ' + request.srcRepoName + ' to ' + request.dstRepoName);

RepositoryManager repositoryManager = repository.repositoryManager;
def srcRepo = repositoryManager.get(request.srcRepoName);
StorageFacet srcStorageFacet = srcRepo.facet(StorageFacet);
def srcTx = srcStorageFacet.txSupplier().get();

class SrcFormat extends Format {
    SrcFormat(String format) {
        super(format);
    }
};

try {
    srcTx.begin();
    log.info('syncRepos. Try to find source components');
    Iterable<Component> srcComponents = srcTx.findComponents(Query.builder().where('1').eq(1).build(), [srcRepo]);
    log.info('syncRepos. There are ' + srcComponents.size() + ' source components found');
    srcTx.commit();
    if (srcComponents != null && srcComponents.size() > 0) {
        log.info('syncRepos. Try to create destination components and assets');
        def dstRepo = repositoryManager.get(request.dstRepoName);
        srcComponents.each {srcComponent ->
            srcTx.begin();
            Component dstComponent = null;
            if (srcTx.componentExists(srcComponent.group(), srcComponent.name(), srcComponent.version(), dstRepo)) {
                dstComponent = srcTx.findComponents(Query.builder().where('name').eq(srcComponent.name()).build(), [srcRepo])[0];
            } else {
                dstComponent = srcTx.createComponent(srcTx.findBucket(dstRepo), new SrcFormat(srcComponent.format()))
                        .name(srcComponent.name())
                        .group(srcComponent.group())
                        .version(srcComponent.version())
                        .attributes(srcComponent.attributes());
                dstComponent.format(srcComponent.format());
                srcTx.saveComponent(dstComponent);
            };
            srcTx.browseAssets(srcComponent).each { srcAsset ->
                if (!srcTx.assetExists(srcAsset.name(), dstRepo)) {
                    def newAsset = srcTx.createAsset(srcTx.findBucket(dstRepo), dstComponent)
                            .name(srcAsset.name())
                            .attributes(srcAsset.attributes())
                            .blobRef(srcAsset.requireBlobRef());
                    newAsset.size(srcAsset.size());
                    newAsset.contentType(srcAsset.contentType());
                    newAsset.lastDownloaded(DateTime.now());
                    srcTx.saveAsset(newAsset);
                };
            };
            srcTx.commit();
        };
        srcTx.begin();
        log.info('syncRepos. Try to find source assets by application/json contentType');
        Iterable<Asset> srcAssets = srcTx.findAssets(Query.builder().where('content_type').eq('application/json').build(), [srcRepo]);
        log.info('syncRepos. There are ' + srcAssets.size() + ' source assets found');
        srcAssets.each { srcAsset ->
            if (!srcTx.assetExists(srcAsset.name(), dstRepo)) {
                def newAsset = srcTx.createAsset(srcTx.findBucket(dstRepo), new SrcFormat(srcAsset.format()))
                        .name(srcAsset.name())
                        .attributes(srcAsset.attributes())
                        .blobRef(srcAsset.requireBlobRef());
                newAsset.size(srcAsset.size());
                newAsset.contentType(srcAsset.contentType());
                newAsset.lastDownloaded(DateTime.now());
                srcTx.saveAsset(newAsset);
            };
        };
        srcTx.commit();
    };
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.error('syncRepos. Exception when sync repos: ' + e.message);
    srcTx.rollback();
    resultCode = -1;
    errMessage = e.message;
} finally {
    srcTx.close();
};

log.info('syncRepos. Try to return result');
def result = JsonOutput.toJson([
        srcRepoName: request.srcRepoName,
        dstRepoName: request.dstRepoName,
        resultCode: resultCode,
        errMessage: errMessage
]);
return result;
```